# Output for Python script within ModelBuilder is empty although defined

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool

For a task I have written a python script that gives a Mosaic Dataset as a final output of some processes.

Inside the properties of my script, inside the Parameters I have defined the following:

```
Label: DTM_Mosaic
Name: DTM_Mosaic
Data Type: Mosaic Dataset
Type: Derived
Direction: Output
```

Inside my script I run, among others, the following lines with `out_mosaic_path`, `out_mosaic_name` being input, :

```
#input (among others) 
out_mosaic_path = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
out_mosaic_name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)
    
DTM_Mosaic_rast = arcpy.management.CreateMosaicDataset(out_mosaic_path, out_mosaic_name, spatial_ref, 1, "32_BIT_FLOAT")

#then fill Mosaic with "AddRasterToMosaicDataset"

#final output
DTM_Mosaic_rast = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(6)
```

**Question**
Then if I drag this script in the model I do see the place holder for my output but no name in the pop-up which you do with the "normal" tools of Esri, making me believe something is wrong? The data itself however is saved inside my GBD. See picture below:

[image]

Comment: Python tool outputs use `arcpy.SetParameter` or `arcpy.SetParameterAsText`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As referenced in your Python code, your output is a **derived** parameter. From your screen shot, with the empty hover box, this is probably happening as you haven't filled in the required parameters up-stream of the tool that make up this derived parameter. In this case, this would be the output GDB and the mosaic name.

Further, in the code of your script tool, you are returning the output with `DTM_Mosaic_rast = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(6)`. You don't "Get" this parameter, as a derived parameter, you need to "Set" it. (See the comment from Bjorn on your original question)

Read more details about it on the [setting script tool parameters](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/setting-script-tool-parameters.htm).

Comment: Thank you, "Set" made it work. Somehow I missed that differnce each time in the documentation.